# Windows secure file copy

Tags: windows, sftp, copy

I'd like to setup a secure file copy to some of my servers. A particular login (not Active Directory or Windows login) would have access to a starting point (e.g. c:\a\www) and then that login would have full power to do anything to the files and folders in and under that starting point, but could not step outside of the starting point.

Which server program would you recommend to do this? Are there any that give access to various starting points at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

I have used [CrushFTP](http://www.crushftp.com) to do this.  It supports a number of protcols and allows access only to folders associated with the login.  Too many other features to list here.  It runs on Windows and other OSs.  Eval is available and support is great even during eval period.

Comment: CrushFTP has an awesome feature set.